# WP Google Suggest plug-in / JQuery submit on select

Tags: jquery, search, select

The following code is from the [WP Google Suggest](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-suggest/) plug-in

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.googleSuggest = function (opts) {
        var services = {
            youtube: 'youtube',
            books: 'books',
            products: 'products',
            news: 'news',
            images: 'img',
            web: 'psy'
        };
        opts = $.extend({
            service: 'web',
            secure: false
        }, opts);
        opts.source = function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http' + (opts.secure ? 's' : '') + '://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    q: request.term,
                    client: services['youtube'],
                    nolabels: 't'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data[1], function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: $("<span>").html(item[0]).text()
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        };
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete(opts);
        });
    };
    $('#s').googleSuggest();
})(jQuery);
```

It is supposed to add a google suggest autocomplete search options in the Wordpress search field. The problem is that when you select the suggested search string, the form is just populated, but not submitted. You need to hit enter again in order to submit it. So, the question is how to add submit on select.

Thank you.

==============================================

**Edit: I came back to this code and made some progress.** I added the following code:

```
      opts.select = function(opts) {
      $(this).autocomplete(opts).parents('form').submit();
  }
```

before the "return" line;

```
    return this.each(function () {
..
```

Now, if I move up and down the auto-suggest results with the arrows, and hit enter, the form gets submitted with the correct string.

However, if the suggestion is clicked with a mouse, the original search string that was typed is submitted. An example of the behavior is as follows:

Search string entered in the form: one two
Automatic suggestions:

one two three

one two three four

one two three four five

When I click one of the automatic suggestions with the mouse, let's say "one two three four", it goes in the search field. The form gets submitted, but then it turns out that it was submitted with the original typed string "one two".

Thank you for any suggestions that you might have.

=======================================

I finally managed to solve the issue with an alternative code:

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#s").autocomplete({
      select: function (event, ui) {
         var selectedObj = ui.item;              
         $("#s").val(selectedObj.value);
         $('#cse-search-box').submit();
         },
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=?",
                { 
                  "hl":"bg", // Language                  
                  "jsonp":"suggestCallBack", // jsonp callback function name
                  "q":request.term, // query term
                  "client":"youtube" // force youtube style response, i.e. jsonp
                }
            );
            suggestCallBack = function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data[1], function(key, val) {
                    suggestions.push({"value":val[0]});
                });
                suggestions.length = 10; // prune suggestions list to only 5 items
                response(suggestions);


            };


        },
    });


});
```

The code was provided by the user [PSR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937892/psr) in a different question. It had to be modified a bit. The original code started with:

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp

$(document).ready(function () {
```

For Wordpress it had to start with:

```
var suggestCallBack; // global var for autocomplete jsonp

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Case closed.